# Alternative to deprecated e.which, to prevent the typing of non-numerical characters?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events

I have a really simple solution, making use of `e.which`, to prevent the typing of non-numerical characters in an input field:

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

However, since `e.which` has been deprecated, is there another simple solution I can use to **solve this exact problem** instead? Here is a demo on CodePen if that helps: https://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/YzWmaMp?editors=1111

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Answer (score 0):

Was able to use e.key, like luk2302 suggested in the comments:

```
// Only allow the input of numerical characters and other essential keys
if (
  e.key !== '1'
  && e.key !== '2'
  && e.key !== '3'
  && e.key !== '4'
  && e.key !== '5'
  && e.key !== '6'
  && e.key !== '7'
  && e.key !== '8'
  && e.key !== '9'
  && e.key !== '0'
  && e.key !== 'Tab'
  && e.key !== 'Backspace'
  && e.key !== 'ArrowLeft'
  && e.key !== 'ArrowRight'
) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```